# React & Typescript - Is it possible to prevent a parameter to be sent if other parameter is sent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use react and typescript.

I want to be sure that only 1 prop from 3 will be sent. I have defined such interfaces:

```
interface General {
  prop1?: boolean
  prop2?: boolean
}

interface Option1 extends General {
  prop3: boolean
}

interface Option2 extends General {
  prop4: boolean
}

interface Option3 extends General {
  prop5: boolean
}

type Option1orOtion2orOption3 = Option1 | Option2 | Option3
```

I use it like this:

```
export default function MyFunc({prop1 = true, prop2 = true, ...props } : Option1orOtion2orOption3 ) {
  return <></>
}
```

I want to get a error when I try to do that , I don't want someone to pass both `prop3` and `prop4` and `prop5`.

```
<MyFunc prop1={true} prop3 prop4 prop5 />
```

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the FC interface exposed by React? it might work with:

> `FC<Option1 | Option2 | Option3>`

but I'm not really sure this is an healthy pattern :/

You might want to create three separate components, even if it generates a bit of code duplication.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it with the `FC` interface exposed by React, but it still there is the same behavior...

Comment: I tried a few things myself, unfortunately it seems like the way typescript and React work together won't allow you to raise an error while using discriminative union... The next best thing would be to create three separate components :/

Comment: Thanks for trying, but still prefer to avoid creating three components. Thanks again.